# PHPBB3 in GlassFish4

Tags: php, glassfish-4, phpbb3, quercus

I'm trying to run [PHPBB3 forums](https://www.phpbb.com/downloads/) in `Glassfish 4` using [quercus 4.0.39](http://quercus.caucho.com/)
but I'm getting the error below error,  i made `test page` contains `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and worked fine ,I don't know anything about `PHP`

```
com.caucho.quercus.UnimplementedException: `mb_substitute_character' has not been implemented.
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` always worked fine, but please make sure the 'mbstring' libary already included.
[image]

Comment: how to check this ? because the `test.php` doesn't show anything about `mbstring`

Comment: @SShehab http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php may helpful.